# Are there any Church Fathers that Martin Luther particularly disliked?

Tags: church-fathers, martin-luther

I know in some of his writings Luther condemns Jerome for writing "virginity merits heaven and marriage the earth". Are there any other Church Fathers and any sayings/writings Luther particularly disregarded?

Comment: It's possible to dislike a Church Father without disregarding him. Indeed, to respond with written reasons why one disagrees with something said, shows due consideration of the point of disagreement. It actually shows respect to respond, rather than treating the person, or the matter, with contempt that might be felt due. Well, as long as the response is not full of contempt! In Luther's day, tracts with cartoons were exchanged. But anyone insulted pictorially would retaliate in kind. That was par for the course back then. Can you expand your question, please, citing references?

Comment: This needs a link to where Luther writes about Jerome.